# Contract Renewal Bundle

Tags: netsuite

Is there a way or a script to set the contract item as inactive or cancel while keeping the Contract active?

we need to set a selective item from the contract as inactive and this should block it from showing in the case management list.

Regards

Comment: can you elaborate your question, please

Comment: Ok, lets say we have a contract for customer X and this contract was created from a sales order have the items 1- Support 2- Technical managed service.

Comment: Then after running the Script R03...the contract items will be created and the contract status will change from pending to active. Then we had a case with this customer and we wanted to remove technical managed services from the contract items. so what we did is the following: 1- selected the contract item and set it inactive, but still it showed as active (as if this flag had no effect on the level of the line)

Comment: 2-we tried to create a downsell to the contract, but still it created a new contract item with a negative amount and now both lines are showing as active. So eventually what we need to cancel or remove or inactivate this contract item from the contract.